# What does "$>" represent in Ruby documentation?

Tags: ruby

As in:

```
def PP.pp(obj, out=$>, width=79)
...
```

This is from the `pp` method of the `PP` class:
http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/pp/rdoc/PP.html#method-c-pp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$>` is the IO destination for Kernel#print (and therefore `puts`), and other output methods. It *defaults* to $stdout, but can be changed to change the behavior of `print`, `printf`, `puts`, etc.